# Is it possible to start rabbit-mq server on mobile device? Should i use CloudAMQP with Android?

Tags: rabbitmq, messaging, cloudamqp

I want to make communication between mobile app and desktop app using RabbitMQ for messaging. Is it possible to start **rabbitmq-server on mobile device** like on PC or you have to use **CloudAMQP** for that (like here: https://www.cloudamqp.com/blog/2015-07-29-rabbitmq-on-android.html)?

Comment: Why you want to start RabbtMQ server on mobile? Better start it on your PC. Publish/consume messages from your mobile/PC to that RabbitMQ server.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/41337444/cannot-connect-to-rabbitmq-server-from-remote-machine-android-device/41343420#41343420